# Issue after upgrading Sitefinity 6.3 (Windows Azure Webproject) to Sitefinity 7.0

Tags: azure, upgrade, sitefinity, azure-sdk-.net

I have a website developed in Sitefinity 6.3 that is deployed on windows Azure (website deployed in Cloud Service). Now I have upgraded the project to sitefinity 7.0 as mentioned on their [migration page](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/upgrading-your-sitefinity-6.3-project-to-the-latest-version).

### Project upgraded successfully, and I followied the steps to remove & add References, but then I ran the project & it showed me following error:

```
Assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=7.0.5100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563' 
uses 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
which has a higher version than referenced assembly
```

### 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

### Then I installed the Azure SDK version 2.2, then following error was displaying:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its 
dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect 
format.


Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'msshrtmi' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = msshrtmi
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: msshrtmi | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/user/Projects/TestTime/Code/From Svn/Unpublished/TestTime/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\user\Projects\TestTime\Code\From Svn\Unpublished\TestTime\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\user\Projects\TestTime\Code\From Svn\Unpublished\TestTime\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/eaa8f4f5/4dd032f8/msshrtmi.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/eaa8f4f5/4dd032f8/msshrtmi/msshrtmi.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/user/Projects/TestTime/Code/From Svn/Unpublished/TestTime/bin/msshrtmi.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.


Stack Trace:


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstReques
```

---

### I tried setting following tag in web.config :

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"  />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding
```

---

I also copied the related dlls in bin folder & added reference to project.
But nothing seemed to work for me, Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Edit: ------------------------

Thanks [DrewG] for sharing important info. 
I followed all the steps as DrewG mentioned. Then I got error when I ran the project in Visual Studio for Post Build task, then I removed that task & Changed following setting in web.config:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0"/>
```

to

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0"/>
```

Then it run perfectly, Then I removed the References folder, then It also run perfectly.
Now, I could not recognise wht was fixed by DrewG's steps, but after reverting all the steps it's working correct. **I would like to know what might be fixed?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem caused from running the project locally. It's trying to load the 64 bit version of that dll (msshrtmi.dll).

Azure is wanting the 64 bit version of the .dll but you either need to use the 32bit version when you run locally or you need to setup a site in IIS with a 64bit app pool to be able to test locally.

I came up with a bit of a hack to get this to work on our azure sites but it has been working before and after an upgrade to Sitefinity 7 so maybe it will help you out.

I copied the 64bit and 32bit msshrtmi.dll files to a folder named References in the same directory as the .sln file. Then I wrote a quick .bat file and added it as a Post Build Task for the project that passes my current build profile.

**Note:** I have a Build profile with the name "Azure" that I use to update some other settings rather than using Thunder. The Azure build profile is basically just a copy of Release, but I like to test Release builds locally too.

Build task looks like this

```
call $(SolutionDir)References\AZURE.bat $(ConfigurationName) $(SolutionDir)
```

AZURE.bat file looks like this

```
If %1 == Azure echo "Copying 64bit version of msshrtmi.dll"
If %1 == Azure  copy %2\References\64\msshrtmi.dll %2\YourProject\Bin\msshrtmi.dll
If NOT %1 == Azure echo "Copying 32bit version of msshrtmi.dll"
If NOT %1 == Azure  copy %2\References\32\msshrtmi.dll %2\YourProject\Bin\msshrtmi.dll
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for important info sharing. Plz. see my post.

Comment: @user1400290 If I had to guess, I'd say you copied the right version of the .dll to your bin directory at some point during all of this. Does it still work when you deploy to Azure or do you get the BadImageFormatException again?

Comment: Well that's I also most suitable reason, I will upload it on Azure at some later point of time. Thanks